# How to get Android App screen Load time using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have created test by recording mobile app trafic and it contains all api calls . so far it is good. I want to achive page load time along with this. is there any plugin or solution avilabel to get the screen load time using jmeter same as we do using webdriver plugin for web applications.

Answer (score 0):

App screen load time means not only API but GUI rendering. Considering that, I dont think jmeter can help.

What can?

1. Stop watch...Very bad answer but think what a user experience while operating is the time.
2. Check andriod UI montitoring tools;-
   https://developer.android.com/training/testing/performance

Thats what I know.